# Why $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}=-\ln(1-e^{ix})$ in $\mathcal{D}'$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Functions in $\mathcal{D}$ are finite test functions in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

$\mathcal{D}'$ are distributions (genralized functions)

Do I have to check that $\forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}$: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^a\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x < \infty,$$ or what?

Comment: Not quite sure about the question, but maybe this will help: Your sum is just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(e^{ix})^n}{n}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ is a well known power series...

Comment: Why is it true, if we deal with generalized functions?

Comment: I don't know what "finite test functions", "distributions" and etc. are (well, distributions in probability I know), but the infinite series in your question converges only for complex with absolute value *less* than one so I don't think the equality is true for any real. For one, for any real f the form $\;x=2\pi k\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , you get there the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: @Timbuc The series converges pointwise (locally uniformly even) on $\mathbb{R}\setminus 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user228494 If you want to show that the series converges to $-\log (1-e^{ix})$ in the sense of distributions, then you must show that $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) e^{inx}\,dx = -\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x)\log (1-e^{ix})\,dx$$ for every $\phi \in D$. [A priori, that gives the _weak_ convergence of the sequence, but the topology on the space of distributions is such that weakly convergent sequences are strongly convergent.]

Comment: @DanielFischer I can believe that, though out of my head I can't see it straightly. Yet the OP didn't distinguish between different reals and thus my comment

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier series for $f(x)=-\ln(1-e^{ix})$ converges uniformly to $f$ for $x \in [\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ for any fixed $\delta > 0$. For $n \ne 0$, the Fourier coefficient $c_n$ satisfies
\begin{align}
    2\pi c_n & =\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-inx}f(x)dx \\ & =\frac{e^{-inx}-1}{-in}f(x)|_{x=0}^{2\pi}-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-inx}-1}{-in}f'(x)dx \\
     & = -\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-inx}-1}{in}\frac{ie^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}dx.
\end{align}
For $n > 0$, $e^{inx}-1=(e^{ix}-1)(1+e^{ix}+e^{2ix}+\cdots+e^{i(n-1)x})$. So you can directly determine all of the Fourier coefficients, and you find that--as expected--the Fourier series for $f$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{n}$. By Abel's theorem for power series,
$$
             \lim_{r\uparrow 1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^{n}e^{inx}}{n}=f(x),
$$
and the convergence is uniform in $r$ for $x\in [\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ if $\delta > 0$. That also gives you some uniform bounds, knowing the power series $F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n}$.

Comment: Why does Fourier series for f converge uniformly?

Comment: It converges uniformly on an interval $[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ because the function you're expanding in a Fourier series is continuously differentiable on $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @user228494 : I forgot to mention that $f$ is absolutely integrable, too.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts because the function is $C^1[\delta,2\pi -\delta]$ and integrable on $[-\delta,\delta]$. Of course from partial summation we can avoid the Dirichlet kernel and just say $ f(x)=\sum_n e^{ix}\frac{e^{inx}-1}{e^{ix}-1} (\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})$ converges absolutely